# How to change DSpace JSPUI main window info

Tags: dspace

I know in the directory `webapps/jspui/layouts` I can modify the navigation bar, the title and the bottom of the page. But where is the file to modify the body? I can't find that file to change it.

Dspace version: 5.1

What goes between the header and footer, where is the communities and data collections, authors, dates, etc.

Anyone know where are the files to edit this part of the page.

[image: imagen description]

Comment: Please specify if you are using XMLUI or JSPUI.  The answer will differ based on which you use.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one single file you can modify for the body. It will depend on exactly what you're trying to achieve, so it'd be great if you could edit your question to include more detail. Your DSpace version would also be good to know.

The `[dspace-src]/dspace-jspui/src/main/webapp` folder contains a number of files (some in subdirectories) for specific parts of the main content area, for example [home.jsp](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-jspui/src/main/webapp/home.jsp) for the repository home page, [display-item.jsp](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-jspui/src/main/webapp/display-item.jsp) for an item page etc.

Please also be aware that you shouldn't change files under `[dspace]/webapps` directly; any changes there will be lost when you rebuild / upgrade DSpace. Instead, you should make changes under `[dspace-src]` and run maven/ant to make the changes live. Have a look at the DSpace wiki page on [JSPUI Configuration and Customization](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/JSPUI+Configuration+and+Customization) for details.